# How to set the terraform provider.other_region variable?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, provider

Looking at this example:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/elasticache_global_replication_group

The secondary region is referencing the aws.other_region variable, however the aws provider spec does not have an 'other_region' field

When I try to set that manually to 'us-west-1' for example it fails with failed to install provider

Answer (score 0):

`other_region` provider can be defined like.

```
provider "aws" {
  region = "us-west-2"
}

provider "aws" {
  alias = "other_region"
  region = "us-west-1"
}
```

Then you can use it on resources like.

```
resource "aws_elasticache_replication_group" "secondary" {
  provider = aws.other_region

  replication_group_id          = "example-secondary"
}
```